# Why does bêta have an accent?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques

I just came across "bêta" used to mean "beta version of software", as in "Android Auto : il vous suffit désormais d’un smartphone Android pour tester la bêta".

https://www.frandroid.com/marques/google/1009123_android-auto-il-vous-suffit-desormais-dun-smartphone-android-pour-tester-la-beta

I learned that the accent circonflex was invented to mark a vowel length distinction that is now obsolete, and usually hints that a letter was removed in the past. Does the usage of "beta" go back so far? I would have assumed describing software as "beta" to be a 20th century phenomenon, and besides, the Greek letter beta is not spelled with an accent in French (selon my dictionary).

Answer (score 7):

The ***ê*** letter has been chosen to represent the ancient Greek ***ῆ*** (*êta*) of *β**ῆ**τα* (modern Greek *ή*). It corresponds to an open long vowel [ɛː] while AmE uses [eɪ] and BrE uses [i] instead <sup>1</sup>.

The French circumflex mark here the length of the vowel and not a letter that would have disappeared.

*Êta* is also present in these other letters from the Greek alphabet:

> ***zêta***: *ζ**ῆ**τα*:

> ***êta***: ***ἦ**τα*

> ***thêta***: *θ**ῆ**τα*

No accent is needed with ***delta*** because of the following *l*. The Greek vowel is different too (*epsilon* representing the short closed vowel [e]): *δ**έ**λτα*

An acute accent is required in the last Greek letter to represent this same [e] in French:

> ***oméga***: *ὦ μ**έ**γα*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For english usage, see [Why are Greek letters pronounced incorrectly in scientific English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11363/)</sub>

Comment: British English uses [i]. In North America it's always [eɪ], so the first syllable is identical to the word "bay".

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks! Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

The Greek letter is usually spelt *bêta*. But the use of the word as in *version beta* is indifferently spelt with or without the circumflex.

- Android 12 : [comment installer la version bêta du nouvel OS](https://www.cnetfrance.fr/news/android-12-comment-installer-la-version-beta-du-nouvel-os-de-google-39922957.htm)
- [Logiciel en version beta](https://framalibre.org/versions/logiciel-en-version-beta)

Anyway whether *bêta* ot *beta* it is still pronounced [bɛta].

If you look at the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beta) it says:

> **beta**
> *(Non standard) Variante de* bêta.
> *Les cellules **beta***.